# How can I group by my columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How can I group by Time?  I tried this, but it gives the error "Invalid column name 'Time'.":

```
select Count(Page) as VisitingCount, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Date, 108) as [Time]
from scr_SecuristLog   
where Date between '2009-05-04 00:00:00' and '2009-05-06 14:58'  
and [user] in (select USERNAME from scr_CustomerAuthorities)  
group by [Time] order by [VisitingCount] asc
```

Comment: Is the error that column time doesnt exist ? I think you need to group by the date convert rather than the name [Time]

Comment: Guess I need to learn to type slower if identical answers that come later are going to be the ones that get accepted ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Time] is a column alias. Try

```
SELECT 
      COUNT(Page) AS VisitingCount
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),Date, 108) AS [Time] 
FROM
    scr_SecuristLog   
WHERE
    Date BETWEEN '2009-05-04 00:00:00' AND '2009-05-06 14:58'  
    AND
    [user] IN (
                SELECT 
                    USERNAME             
                FROM
                    scr_CustomerAuthorities 
                )  
GROUP BY
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),Date, 108) 
ORDER BY
    [VisitingCount] ASC
```

Comment: Guess I need to learn to type slower if identical answers that come later are going to be the ones that get accepted ;)

Comment: I second this answer. Basically, you have to group by the same expression you use in the SELECT list. The alias won't do.

Comment: Simply put, you cannot group by [Time] because [Time] does not exists at the "group by" level.

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),Date, 108)
```

Always make sure you group by everything in your select clause that does not have an aggregate function around it.

Comment: You're missing a closing brace

Comment: Thanks, I just copied & pasted from the original post. Must have missed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
select Count(Page) as VisitingCount,CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),Date, 108) as [Time] from scr_SecuristLog   
where Date between '2009-05-04 00:00:00' and '2009-05-06 14:58'  
and [user] in(select USERNAME             
    from scr_CustomerAuthorities )  
group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),Date, 108) order by [VisitingCount] asc
```

I modified the `GROUP BY` to include the actual expression for `[Time]`, rather than the column alias (since this can't be used in the `GROUP BY`, only the `ORDER BY`)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Date is a column here, but it's a keyword and not quoted. Perhaps that's the issue (not tested though):

```
select Count(Page) as VisitingCount,CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),[Date], 108) as [Time] from scr_SecuristLog   
where [Date] between '2009-05-04 00:00:00' and '2009-05-06 14:58'  
and [user] in(select USERNAME             
    from scr_CustomerAuthorities )  
group by [Time] order by [VisitingCount] asc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to repeat the date conversion (Sometimes calculation is a bit more intensive than simple conversion), then you can use something like this:

```
select * 
from ( select Count(page) .., ... As [Date] from ... where ...) UG
group by UG.[Date]
```

Notice that you *have* to give the 'UG' name to internal select and that this will be most likely and in most cases less efficient than repeating the conversion expression in original grouping.
Also your whole expression is likely to change... But so just you know that it is possible.